# How to create full width bottom borders on the :after pseudo elements on the tbody of a table?

Tags: html, css

Right now I'm trying to add bottom borders to each `tbody` within a table. 
Currently I have borders around my `tr` elements in general but I would like to preserve those while adding bottom borders to the `tbody`.

I'm currently using pseudo elements in my solution and produces the effect I want but for some reason the background of the pseudo element isn't at 100% width.

I would like to know how to create full width bottom borders on the `tbody` element while still preserving the borders on the `tr` elements?

Here's a fiddle of my current problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/4eucexwb/

I'm also open to JavaScript/jQuery solutions too.

Comment: Is the number of columns fixed?

Comment: @z0mBi3 No they are not

Answer (score 0):

Instead of styling the pseudo element ::after give style border-bottom to tbody like this.

```
.table tbody{
  border-bottom: 0.5rem solid #e6e6f5;
}
```

**Edited:**
After reading your code line by line your solution is [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/4eucexwb/2/). You're creating pseudo element as table row, and your table has 4 `td` therefore pseudo element takes width equal to first `td`. Problem was position. I gave `position: relative;` to table class and `position: absolute;` to your pseudo element and some width to it. Moreover you can set width base on media queries for better style.

Updated CSS.

```
html {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2rem;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;         //----First change
  thead {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #e6e6f5;
    th {
      padding: 0 0.75rem;
    }
  }
  tbody {
    &:after {
      content: '';
      display: table-row;
      background: #e6e6f5;
      height: 0.5rem;
      border-left: 1px solid #d0d0dd;
      border-right: 1px solid #d0d0dd;
      position: absolute;       //-----Second change
      width: 99.7%;            //------Third change
    }
    &:last-child:after {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0dd;
    }
  }
  tbody,
  tfoot {
    td {
      padding: 0 0.75rem;
    }
  }
  tr {
    height: 1.75rem;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0dd;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you lose the borders on the first and last tr elements which I said I'd like to keep.

Answer (score 0):

I' ve modificated Khurrams solutions a little bit and I think this is what you want.

```
html {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2rem;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6f5;
  thead {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #e6e6f5;
    th {
      padding: 0 0.75rem;
    }
  }
  tbody {
    background-color: #fff;
    &:last-child:after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0dd;
    }
    &:after {
      content: '';
      background-color:#e6e6f5;
      display: table-row;
      height: 0.5rem;
      border-left: 1px solid #d0d0dd;
      border-right: 1px solid #d0d0dd;
    }
  }
  tbody, tfoot {
    td {
      padding: 0 0.75rem;
    }
  }
  tr {
    height: 1.75rem;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0dd;
  }
}
```

I gave a background-color to the table (#e6e6f5) and the tbody (white) elements. After that the solutions is nearly 90 %. The last thing to do is to give the tbody:after pseudo-element a background-color of #e6e6f5.

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: This is very close!
The border-right still doesn't appear on both tbody:after pseudo element.
Also for some reason the #d0d0dd bottom-border on the last tbody doesn't seem to be full width.

But very very close, this definitely helps. I'll look into it more. 
Thanks